# Error NumberFormatException: For input string: "2.0" starting Jdeveloper

Tags: oracle, jdeveloper

I have a fresh VM with Oracle 12c 12.2.1.1 downloaded from oracle website, after test Admin and SOA server I installed BPM and shutdown VM.

Now when I try to start Jdeveloper I have this error:

```
 Oracle JDeveloper 12c Development Build 12.2.1.1.0
 Copyright (c) 1997, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch(Framework.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.EquinoxLauncher.internalInit(EquinoxLauncher.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.EquinoxLauncher.init(EquinoxLauncher.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.init(Equinox.java:178)
    at org.netbeans.modules.netbinox.Netbinox.init(Netbinox.java:84)
    at org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso.prepare(Netigso.java:167)
    at org.netbeans.NetigsoHandle.turnOn(NetigsoHandle.java:138)
    at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(ModuleManager.java:1346)
    at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(ModuleManager.java:1163)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.installNew(ModuleList.java:340)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.trigger(ModuleList.java:276)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleSystem.restore(ModuleSystem.java:301)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Main.java:181)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Main.java:150)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Main.java:307)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(TopThreadGroup.java:123)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:225)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2.0"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateBuilder.createBundleDescription(StateBuilder.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateObjectFactoryImpl.createBundleDescription(StateObjectFactoryImpl.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.readStateData(BaseStorage.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.getStateManager(BaseStorage.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.getState(BaseAdaptor.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.frameworkStart(BaseStorage.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.frameworkStart(BaseAdaptor.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start(SystemBundleActivator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 19 more
```

I search in the web and find this [link](http://www.hkmconsultingllc.com/blog/oracle/jdeveloper-12c-fails-start-yosemite/) so I follow and delete the `<HOME>/.jdeveloper/system12.1.3.0.41.140521.1008/system_cache` folder and the folders for 12.2.1 and 12.2.1.1 without success. Any idea?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue with the pre-build VM from OTN.

I cleared all `<HOME>/.jdeveloper/system12.*/system_cache` folders first: no effect. Completly removing all existing `<HOME>/.jdeveloper/system12.*` folders: also no effect.
I also removed all `<HOME>/.jdeveloper/12.*` folders and restarted JDeveloper.
Still the same error.

But now a single folder was created: `<HOME>/.jdeveloper/12.2.1.1.0` with a `product.conf` file.

In this file the `SetJavaHome` was commented out. It seems that the default JDK is the source of the issue. I changed it to `SetJavaHome /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51`. Saved the file and restarted JDeveloper and now it starts as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue yesterday. Below steps solved my issue.

Thanks to **Henk Jan** for the steps he gave earlier and helped me to resolve it.

Didn't solve the issue after clearing **system*** folder/directory under **/.jdeveloper/**.

I cleared the entire **/.jdeveloper/** directory.

I didn't change the SetJavaHome in **product.conf** file from **/.jdeveloper/12.2.1.3/**

Restarted the **JDeveloper** and it starts as expected.